# How to publish HTML5 game in Chrome Web Store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store, manifest.json

I have my HTML5 game hosted in www.mygame.com and I followed on this [doc](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest) the result show only visit website button in Chrome web store:

[image: visit website button]

The question is how to add my game shortcut in chrome://apps/ and when users click on game icon will link to www.mygame.com

This is my `manifest.json`:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Math Booster",
    "description": "Try to solve basic math in short time",
    "version": "1.1",
    "icons": { 
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "app": {
        "urls": [
            "http://photogap.me/mathbooster"
        ],
        "launch": {
            "web_url": "http://photogap.me/mathbooster"
        }
    },
    "permissions": ["unlimitedStorage","notifications"]
}
```

Comment: Works for me on Chrome OS. Probably because Chrome Apps are being removed on other platforms: https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html

Answer (score 0):

What you have created is a [Hosted App](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/hosted_apps) in Chrome's terminology.

Hosted Apps (and other Chrome Apps as well) are [deprecated on platforms other than Chrome OS](https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html), which would explain what you're seeing.

Note that at an unspecified date in 2017, those listings will simply disappear from CWS for other platforms.

Google's official position is "transition to [Progressive Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/)".

Comment: (posting it as an answer to serve as canonical duplicate target)