# Chrome webstore app not showing add to Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I've created an app and it has been published but it does not show add to Chrome when I check the page [Link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/online-notepad/jmnimaabpfgblbgkldcenjphclfadgkd). Instead it shows just visit website. I am wondering what's going on.

The manifest of the app is as follows, have I done something wrong?

```
{
    "name": "Online Notepad",
    "version": "4.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Save your notes online for free and share them with friends!",
    "app": {
            "urls": ["https://notepad.pw/"],
            "launch": {
                    "web_url": "https://notepad.pw/"
            }
        },
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "notifications"
    ]
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45083171/how-to-publish-html5-game-in-chrome-web-store

Comment: thanks, i guess i'll have to create an extension.